# error with trying to add values in list<class> by Mysql.reader

Tags: c#, mysql, list, xamarin

shortcut of kitchen = kok

i have list of kok and i fill it with this:

```
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    cone = cone + 1;
                    if (reader["isclean"] != System.DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        Koks.Add(new AppLists.KOK { ID = (sbyte)reader["ID"], UserID = (int)reader["userID"], IsClean = (sbyte)reader["isclean"], BDate = (DateTime)reader["Bdate"], EDate = (DateTime)reader["Edate"] });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Koks.Add(new AppLists.KOK { ID = (sbyte)reader["ID"], UserID = (int)reader["userID"], IsClean = 0, BDate = (DateTime)reader["Bdate"], EDate = (DateTime)reader["Edate"] });

                    }
                }
```

i get error:

```
             System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

and if i don't put the if (reader["isclean"] != System.DBNull.Value)
i get error :

```
               System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.SByte'.
```

where IsClean tinyint and all data of IsClean in the DB is null
any subjection please

Comment: The contructor for the class requires five parameters. You are trying to pass just one parameter. Need to add the others but with the correct syntax for named parameters, IE _new KOK(Id:reader["ID"],..._

Comment: This does not do what you think it does: `new AppLists.KOK (Id = <expression>`, this will try to assign a value to something locally named Id, not to the Id property of the KOK object you're trying to create. You either need to pass the value of the expression to the constructor, as you've defined one that takes parameters, or use proper object initialization syntax, like `new KOK { Id = <expression> }`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a casing issue. The parameter name is `id` where as the code is referencing a `Id`.

Comment: From what I see in the line `public KOK(byte id , int userid ,byte isclean , DateTime Bdat,DateTime Edate)` the parameter name is lower cased.

Comment: Still that's not the main reason behind the error. Constructor requires five parameters not one, then if you want to pass named parameters your need the syntax _parameter:value_.

Comment: @BabakNaffas i find the problem i should use {} not () but now i have other problem related

Answer (score 0):

by mjwills THX

You forgot to set Koks. public List Koks = new List();